# java.lang.NullPointerException:on spinner

Tags: java, android

the error im getting is this one -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a
```

Im creating a game dialog where the user gets to choose a suit. It seems to be blowing up when I try to set the adapter is there anything wrong here? The app crashes.

```
private void showChooseSuitDialog(){
        final Dialog chooseSuitDialog = new Dialog(myContext);
        chooseSuitDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        chooseSuitDialog.setContentView(R.layout.choose_suit_dialog);
        final Spinner suitSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.suitSpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(myContext, R.array.suits, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        suitSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
//        Button okButton = (Button) chooseSuitDialog.findViewById(R.id.okButton);
//        okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                validSuit = (suitSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()+1) * 100;
//                String suitText = "";
//                if(validSuit == 100){
//                    suitText = "Diamonds";
//                }else if(validSuit == 200){
//                    suitText = "Clubs";
//                }else if(validSuit == 300) {
//                    suitText = "Hearts";
//                }else {
//                    suitText = "Spades";
//                }
//                chooseSuitDialog.dismiss();
//                Toast.makeText(myContext, "You chose " //+suitText,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//        });
        chooseSuitDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code to initialize spinner

```
final Spinner suitSpinner = (Spinner)chooseSuitDialog.findViewById(R.id.suitSpinner);
```

Comment: accept this answer if worked for you.Thank you